# Passing data via POST from an element to controller/model Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, post, model, controller

I am pretty new to cakephp, I have an uploader form and would like to pass all of the data using POST to the controller and model so that it will save to the database. So far there are no cakephp errors occuring but no data is being passed.

Controller Code:

```
<?php class Controller extends AppController {

  public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->File->create();
        if ($this->File->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your file has been liberated :)'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong!'));
        }
    }
}
}?>
```

View Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('File'); ?>
<input type="uploader" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

Model Code:

```
<?php class File extends AppModel {}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check [input specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT)  you can see there, that there are no "uploader" value for `type` attribute.  Maybe you mean `type="file"`.

Also, if you want to upload files, please, use

```
echo $this->Form->create('File', array('type' => 'file'));
```

this will produce correct enctype attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. such enctype needed if you send files by POST.

Also, you use style: `style="visibility: hidden;"` which should hide file input field, so, maybe you use some flash uploader or ajax, but this is not demonstrated in your code. If you provide more code, we can provide more concrete help to you.

and counter question: how you debug your code?